# How do I click on a button through a div ? (pointer-events didn't work)

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I'm building a modal, but I have a problem.

First run the  script below.

The problem is that I cannot click the toggle button. Any ideas? I tried to use "pointer-events: none" but unfortunately it didn't work the way I expected.

```js
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const layer = document.querySelector(".layer");
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector(".toggleBtn");
const closeModalBtn = document.querySelector(".closeModalBtn");

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.classList.toggle("hide")
});

closeModalBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.classList.add("hide");
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.modal {
  width: 100px;

  background: silver;
  text-align: center;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: 120ms;
}

.layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;

}

.hide {
  transform: scale(0);
}
```

```html
<button class="toggleBtn">Toggle Modal</button>

<div class="layer">
  <div class="modal"> 
    <h6>I'm a modal!</h6>
    <button class="closeModalBtn">Ok</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to click from the UI. Any ideas?

Comment: give z-index: -1 to .layer

Comment: @BülentAkgül then the modal might be hidden by the sites content. Actually just give the button a higher positive z-index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS to layer the button on top of the modal.

```js
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const layer = document.querySelector(".layer");
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector(".toggleBtn");
const closeModalBtn = document.querySelector(".closeModalBtn");

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.classList.toggle("hide")
});

closeModalBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.classList.add("hide");
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

/* Position the button above the modal */
.toggleBtn { position:relative; z-index:1000;}

.modal {
  width: 100px;

  background: silver;
  text-align: center;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: 120ms;
}

.layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;

}

.hide {
  transform: scale(0);
}
```

```html
<button class="toggleBtn">Toggle Modal</button>

<div class="layer">
  <div class="modal"> 
    <h6>I'm a modal!</h6>
    <button class="closeModalBtn">Ok</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @pheianox You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote and mark as "the" answer.

Comment: stackoverflow says that I will be able to do that after 4 minutes. . I won't forget :)